# Can't deploy Node restify app to AWS EB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a basic restify node app to AWS EB but when I do I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. The AWS console also shows that the application is in Health: Severe. It seems as though it isn't correctly serving via port 80. Here is my server.js:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello");
    return next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: What do the logs on your EC2 instance(s) say? look in `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`

Comment: Hhhhhhmmmm, it's probably not the source of the issue, but one problem is you have no code to close down your server when it's done. I would suggest you probably want a `response.end();` in there somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though on EB that nginx redirects to node on port 8081, so I changed to that.

Additionally for whatever reason the node instance wasn't being run after "eb deploy". I added "node server.js" in software configuration on aws and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: You can use process.env.PORT, so that you don't hardcode 8081